# Angular, prepopulate data with .run then pass into factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular here. I am trying to data then pass it into a factory for use. I am trying to get the events to fire in a certain order with using the $http within angular. I was pointed in the direction of using .run to do the first population, pass it into the factory, which then passes it into the controllers. The factory has a function which then would allow me to "refresh" the data being shared with the controllers.

I received some great help setting up the refresh function, but I am struggling get the data to populate initially. Here is my attempt:

```
.run("getDataForLevels", function($http){
    var getIt = $http.get("/assets/images/generated.json")
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    return getIt;
})
.factory("UserService", function($http, getDataForLevels) {

    dataFactory = getDataForLevels;
    dataFactory.currentData = null;

    dataFactory.update = function () {
        return $http.get("/assets/images/generated.json")
            .success(function(data){
                dataFactory.currentData = data;
                return data;
            });
    };

    return dataFactory;

});
```

I then Add the dependency of UserService to the controllers and pass in the data to the controllers. I seem to be betting an error [ng:areq] on this. Any/all help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do  like this :

```
.run("getDataForLevels", function($http){
    var getIt = $http.get("/assets/images/generated.json")
    .success(function(data){
        return data;

        });
    return getIt;
})
```

it only take one argument, as a function.

you can do like this:

```
.run(function($http,$rootScope){
    $http.get("/assets/images/generated.json")
    .success(function(data){
        $rotScope.data=data;

        });
})

.factory("UserService", function($http, $rootScope) {



    dataFactory.update = function () {
        return $http.get("/assets/images/generated.json")

    };

    return dataFactory;

});
```

in controller inject dependencies and do like this:

```
var dataFactory = $rootScope.data;
    dataFactory.currentData = null;
UserService.update ()
        .success(function(data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('error in loading File list');
      });
```

Comment: it appears this does not make the initial get fire before to initialize, because if I put a log in the controller, the userService return is coming back as undefined. I need something that would make the data populate before the factory uses them, something like a .then.

Comment: This takes away the 2 way data binding betwen controllers, I simply want the data to load in, into the controller before the controllers request and use it, then be able to refresh that data being used between both controllers. It seems like this is individual per controller

Comment: Can you show your controller?  What do you mean by the data load in before the controllers request and use it?  You can't easily and probably don't want to delay your controller's creation until the request completes.  If you're taking `dataFactory.currentData` and using that, the object will change in the update.  If you put `dataFactory` itself on your scope instead you should be able to bind to `dataFactory.currentData.userName` for instance.